# Have problem with redirecting to a page after login in nodejs

Tags: node.js, passport.js

i have a little problem

in app.js, line 83, when I tried to redirect to the secret page, the website wasn't redirected to the original page, but it redirected me to a page that has the secrets in the path, but the title is error and instead of seeing my secrets page I see a page with the user id and the email, how can I fix that?
I will appreciate any help

my code is in the following github page
https://github.com/DoronTavor/LearningSecretPage